# SQL MIN across multiple columns with a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, grouping, min

I'm trying to take a table with information as follows:

```
+----+---+---+
| ID | X | Y |
+----+---+---+
| A  | 1 | 3 |
| A  | 1 | 1 |
| A  | 1 | 2 |
| A  | 1 | 7 |
| B  | 2 | 2 |
| B  | 3 | 3 |
| B  | 1 | 9 |
| B  | 2 | 4 |
| B  | 2 | 1 |
| C  | 1 | 1 |
+----+---+---+
```

I'd like to be able to select the minimum across both columns, grouping by the first column - the "X" column is more important than the Y column. So for example, the query should return something like this:

```
+----+---+---+
| ID | X | Y |
+----+---+---+
| A  | 1 | 1 |
| B  | 1 | 9 |
| C  | 1 | 1 |
+----+---+---+
```

Any ideas? I've gone through dozens of posts and experiments and no luck so far.

Thanks,
James

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: but the min Y for ID B is 1, not 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want the *row* that has the minimum x value.  And, if there are duplicates on x, then take the one with the minimum y.

For this, use `row_number()`:

```
select id, x, y
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by x, y) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

If your database does not support window functions, you can still express this in SQL:

```
select t.id, t.x, min(t.y)
from t join
     (select id, MIN(x) as minx
      from t
      group by id
     ) tmin
     on t.id = tmin.id and t.x = tmin.minx
group by t.id, t.x
```

Answer (score 2):

If your RDBMS supports Window Function,

```
SELECT ID, X, Y
FROM
        (
            SELECT ID, X, Y,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY X, Y) rn
            FROM    tableName
        ) d
WHERE   rn  = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58c38/1)

Comment: Works like a charm. For anyone wondering, to get info from other tables via JOINS/etc, joi in the subquery and go from there.